# Not displaying any output

Tags: c++, output, runtime-error

Not displaying any output for the second loop of the function even though it is displaying the output for the cout statements in between the first and the second loop of the function. Enter 3 4 8 5 for cin. I need the scores to be 0 5 1. And the total score to be 6.

Code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

long getMaxScore(vector < long > a){
// Complete this function
long runningSum = 0;
int n = a.size();
vector<long> scores(n);
int j=0;
long totalScore;


for(int i = 0; i < n;)
{   
    scores[j] = runningSum%a[n-1];
    runningSum = runningSum + a[n-1];
    n--;
    j++;    
}

cout<<scores[0]<<endl;
cout<<scores[1]<<endl;
cout<<scores[2]<<endl;

for(long k=0; k<n; k++)
{
    totalScore = 0;
    totalScore+=scores[k];
    cout<<totalScore<<endl;
}

//return totalScore;}

int main() {
int n;
cin >> n;
vector<long> a(n);
for(int a_i = 0; a_i < n; a_i++){
   cin >> a[a_i];
}
long maxScore = getMaxScore(a);
return 0;}
```

Comment: `k<n` : `n` already `0` So this is false (The body of the loop is not executed.）. Also `totalScore = 0;` move to before this loop.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But now, the answer of the totalScore is 1 and it should be 6. I don't get what's wrong with it?

Comment: **`totalScore = 0;` move to before this loop.** (`cout<<totalScore<<endl;` move to after this loop)

Comment: Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: Don't spam tags. This is clearly not C!

Comment: Olaf, I'm really sorry. I'm new to this. I thought that maybe programmers who know C could also help me. I will watch out for this next time.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

The loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < n;)
{   
    scores[j] = runningSum%a[n-1];
    runningSum = runningSum + a[n-1];
    n--;
    j++;    
}
```

ends when `n` is equal to zero.

Hence, by the time the program encounters the loop

```
for(long k=0; k<n; k++)
{
    totalScore = 0;
    totalScore+=scores[k];
    cout<<totalScore<<endl;
}
```

nothing inside the loop executed since `k < n` is false.

**Solution**

I suggest adding a line to reset the value of `n` before the second loop.

```
n = a.size();
for(long k=0; k<n; k++)
{
   ...
}
```

---

Move the line

```
    totalScore = 0;
```

outside the loop to accumulate the score.

```
totalScore = 0;
for(long k=0; k<n; k++)
{
    totalScore += scores[k];
    cout << totalScore << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.
But now, the answer of the totalScore is 1 and it should be 6. I don't get what's wrong with it?